# How to fix an error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'? Function "TO_DATE" not found

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I have data.sql, but I may not change it.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7839, 'JOHN', 'KING', 'MARIA', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, TO_DATE('17-11-1981', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 5000, null);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7698, 'JOHN', 'BLAKE', 'MARIA', 'MANAGER', 7839, TO_DATE('1-5-1981', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 2850, 30);
```

and I have

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "hiredate")
    private LocalDate hired;
  // constructors, getters, setters
```

when I run my MvcApplication I have an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL 
[file:/Users/dh/IdeaProjectsE/employee-catalog/target/classes/data.sql]: 
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7839, 'JOHN', 'KING', 'MARIA', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, TO_DATE('17-11-1981', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 5000, null); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "TO_DATE" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7839, 'JOHN', 'KING', 'MARIA', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, TO_DATE('17-11-1981', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 5000, null) [90022-214]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Also I have application.properties

```
server.port=8080

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialectspring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: `TO_DATE` doesn't exist in H2. You'll need to use `CAST` or string literal in ISO date format

Comment: `PARSEDATETIME('1-5-1981', 'dd-MM-yyyy')` can be tried too

Answer (score 0):

`TO_DATE` is not supported by every database vendor and H2 is one of them. To insert date values in a database using H2 you can just pass a String literal formatted with ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`. So the query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7839, 'JOHN', 'KING', 'MARIA', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, '1981-11-17', 5000, null);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7698, 'JOHN', 'BLAKE', 'MARIA', 'MANAGER', 7839, '1981-05-01', 2850, 30);
```

If you use the `toString()` method on a `LocalDate` object it will be outputted exatly as needed in this case. So when you build the SQL query just pass that String, instead of a LocalDate object.